# MYSQL, COUNT = 0 Error

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, count

MYSQL newbie

My SQL/ASP:

```
sQuery = "SELECT ID, Shop, Make, COUNT(*) AS iTotal From Test.Makes WHERE Shop = " & s & " GROUP BY Make ORDER BY Make ASC;"
```

The table contains 1 line ID=1, Shop=1, Make=Test

When `s = 1`, `iTotal = 1` and everything runs fine, when `s = 0`, iTotal crashes the page with error '80020009'

Is there a way of recording a 0 recordcount

IF iTotal > 0 Then do this else do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if your recordset is not EOF

```
if not rs.EOF Then
    Do your stuff
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for that.

i'm so used to rst.recordcount

Answer (score 0):

You can guarantee you'll always get a result if you get rid of the grouping. From what's posted it looks like you just need to count where `Shop = s`. I say that because you're not grouping on `ID` or `Shop` so those values will be unpredictable in the results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS iTotal FROM Test.Makes WHERE Shop = <your shop value>
```

Basically, if you count *with* grouping and nothing's found, you won't get a result. If you count *without* grouping and nothing's found, you'll get a result of zero.

Also note that your code is susceptible to SQL Injection. See [here](http://bobby-tables.com/asp.html) for information on avoiding this threat in Classic ASP.